# How to run selenium scripts on jenkins server situated in different country?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have created selenium scripts on my local machine using Selenium + Maven + TestNG  and now i want to run the selenium scripts on Jenkins server which is situated in different country where selenium jars are not present. How i can achieve this? Any Solution would be appreciated.

Comment: in which language have you written selenium scripts?

Comment: @Gaurang shah. Selenium with Java

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

1. Need to install Jenkins slave on that machine. (I think you will need Java Client)
2. Make sure that machine also have JDK and Maven.
3. Bind you Jenkins job to run on that particular slave.
4. in you job, apart from taking the checkout of latest code you just need to run following command

   mvn clean test